# VBA Code to Paste SQL Query in Excel with NULL values pasted as "NULL"

Tags: sql, vba

Below is my code to run and post my query results in Excel. The code pastes NULL as 0. I would like the NULLs to be a
pasted as "NULL". I think some type of paste values would work or changing my table from a ".QueryTable" may help. I am not sure what to do. Any suggestions?

```
    'Import Data
    With queryOutputWS.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:=Array(Array( _
        "ODBC;DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=W51SQP-********;Trusted_Connection=Yes;APP=Microsoft Office 2010" _
        ), Array(";DATABASE=*****")), Destination:=queryOutputWS.Range("A1")).QueryTable
        .CommandText = myQuery
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = False
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = False
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = False
        .ListObject.DisplayName = "Query"
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    queryOutputWS.ListObjects("Query").Unlist
```

Comment: Maybe try to change the column properties for those cells to text/generic (i.e not number).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is easier to change the SQL query rather than the VBA code. If you later post the code of your query I could see if what I'm thinking applies, but nevertheless, you could try this:

Suppose the column you want to query and change the values is called `Column1`

In your query, change the `SELECT [...,] Column1 [,...] FROM ...` to:

```
SELECT [...,] IIF(Column1 IS NULL, 'NULL', Column1) [,...] FROM...
```

Let me know if that helps!